# Проверка наличия списка в другом списке

Tags: python, pandas

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не правильно работает в функции ниже?

```
if len(in_db_not_existed) > 0:
    for i in dataframe.values:
        print("*******")
        print(i)
        print(in_db_not_existed.values)
        print("*******")
        if i in in_db_not_existed.values:
            print(True)
```

`in_db_not_existed.values` и `i` это numpy.ndarray которые выглядят примерно так:

```
in_db_not_existed = pd.DataFrame([["Timestamp('2023-05-05 00:00:00')", "150200117","ПУШКИНО_1_РФЦ"], \ 
                                  ["Timestamp('2023-05-05 00:00:00')", "862471210", "Казань_РФЦ_НОВЫЙ"]])
print(in_db_not_existed.values)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame([["Timestamp('2023-05-05 00:00:00')", "862329540" "Санкт_Петербург_РФЦ"], \
                          ["Timestamp('2023-05-05 00:00:00')", "832964666", "Казань_РФЦ_НОВЫЙ"], \
                          ["Timestamp('2023-05-05 00:00:00')", "832963639", "САМАРА_РФЦ"], \
                          ["Timestamp('2023-05-05 00:00:00')", "832963639", "ЖУКОВСКИЙ_РФЦ"], \
                          ["Timestamp('2023-05-05 00:00:00')", "150200117","ПУШКИНО_1_РФЦ"], \
                          ["Timestamp('2023-05-05 00:00:00')", "862471210", "Казань_РФЦ_НОВЫЙ"]])
print(dataframe.values)
```

Мною ожидается что в цикле каждое значение из dataframe.values провериться на наличие в in_db_not_existed.values и выдаст True если есть, но почему True срабатывает всегда, как это можно решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сравнении (многоуровневого) массива, numpy использует поэлементный подход `any` - то есть, если какой-то элемент подсписка равен какому-то элементу другого подсписка, вы получите True. В вашем примере всегда есть совпадение значения Timestamp. Попробуйте изменить в in_db_not_existed в элементе Timestamp секунды и запустите ваш код - теперь True будет только у некоторых элементов (потому что совпадают какие-то другие поля). Для эксплицитного сравнения "все равны всем", можете попробовать явно использовать метод `all` (как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise), например).

Что вы хотите выяснить? Есть ли строки из dataframe в in_db_not_existed? Если да, тогда зачем такое сложноe решение? и вообще, грех пользоваться циклами, если у вас есть весь инструментарий pandas:

```
res = pd.merge(dataframe, in_db_not_existed, how ='inner')
```

res:

```
                                  0          1                 2
0  Timestamp('2023-05-05 00:00:00')  150200117     ПУШКИНО_1_РФЦ
1  Timestamp('2023-05-05 00:00:00')  862471210  Казань_РФЦ_НОВЫЙ
```

это решение покажет вам пересечение ваших датафреймов, то есть те строки, которые есть в обоих. Если, как выяснилось, у вас нужно найти частичное совпадение (в одном фрейме содрержатся все поля друого фрема плюс что-то еще), то можно включить в merge параметр `on`, где указать список нужных столбцов.

Comment: Я не совсем согласен с Вами, цикл берет элемент из основного датафрейма(dataframe) и проверяет есть ли этот элемент в датафрейме(in_db_not_existed), если есть, то код работает дальше.  Но почему то скрипт работает не так как ожидалось.
Все таки in_db_not_existed.values и i это <class 'numpy.ndarray'> мне кажется.
Такое решение я выбрал потому что таблица in_db_not_existed содержит часть столбцов dataframe)

Comment: Автор проверяет каждую строку из всего `dataframe` на содержание в меньшем `in_db_not_existed`

Comment: @Rett_oo еще раз - какова цель вашего изыскания ? найти все строки одного датафрейма в другом или прекратить работу скрипта, если какой-то строки там не окажется. и не путайте in_db_not_existed с in_db_not_existed.values - первое - датафрейм. второе - ndarray.

Comment: @DmitryK ну и что? ничего не межает поменять датафреймы в методе merge местами. самое главное, понять, для чего он это делает.

Comment: Цель вывести список который получится при проверке. Далее значения списка будут добавляться в БД. К примеру если элемент(["Timestamp('2023-05-05 00:00:00')", "150200117","ПУШКИНО_1_РФЦ"]) есть в списке in_db_not_existed, должно быть True или если ["Timestamp('2023-05-05 00:00:00')", "832963639", "САМАРА_РФЦ"] нет в списке in_db_not_existed, должно быть False. Да, мне нужно проверить есть ли в основном фрейме записи идентичные какому то элементу in_db_not_existed.values. И все таки я не путаю DataFrame и ndarray, насколько вижу..

Comment: А вы не гадайте. `type(in_db_not_existed)` и `type(in_db_not_existed.values)` вам все покажут. Еще раз, чем вас не устраивает мое векторизиванное решение?

Comment: Я не гадаю, вроде бы явно указал "in_db_not_existed.values и i это numpy.ndarray". Данное решение мне не подходит поскольку в примере который я привел dataframe  и in_db_not_existed являются равными по ширине списками, на самом деле код выглядит примерно так: `if i[pk_indexes] in in_db_not_existed.values:`. Вкратце in_db_not_existed это таблица из первичных ключей отсутствующих значений в dataframe таблице обрезанной столбцами первичных ключей.  А мне нужно вставить в БД полную строку из dataframe. Поэтому merge inner мне не подходит

Comment: @Rett_oo merge можно ограничивать отдельными столбцами. либо у вас не вполне сформулирован вопрос, либо я чего-то в упор не понимаю (что не исключено).

Comment: Попробую задать вопрос иначе. Есть таблица А со столбцами (date, id, name) и таблица B со столбцами (date,id,name, count, price, status, . . .). На выходе нужно получить строки из таблицы B где  (date, id, name) равны (date,id,name) таблицы А, что бы в дальнейшем эту строку добавить в БД

Comment: Ну так посмотрите документацию. метод merge имеет параметр `on` ( https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html ) - вы можете в него передавать список столбцов, по которому нужно найти совпадения. а в итоге получите полные строки.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, буду разбираться в этом методе. Пока не до конца понимаю его работу вот и сторонюсь его. И все таки интересно, почему поэлементная проверка выдавала True, хотя списки были не одинаковые...

Comment: Но ведь в моём цикле элемент который брался из полного списка сравнивался с не полным списком, а не наоборот.  Если бы было как Вы говорите, то цикл выглядел бы так: `for i in in_db_not_existed.values: if i in dataframe.values: print(True)`. В это случае код код выполнялся на каждой итерации(если есть хотя бы одно совпадение)

Comment: ну вот, не прошло и года, и я понял, о чем вы спрашиваете. я дополнил ответ.